# How do I access 'this' of a controller in unit tests when using controllerAs?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a simple controller:

```
myApp.controller('HelloController', function () {
  this.greeting = 'Hello!';
});
```

I want to test it - but I can't access `$scope` like usual:

```
  beforeEach(inject(function (
    _$rootScope_,
    $controller
  ) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctl = $controller('HelloController', {
      $scope: scope
    });
    scope.$apply();
  }));

  it('should call fetchArticle and set that to a property', function () {
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(scope.greeting).to.equal('hello');
  });
```

How do I check the `this` of `HelloController`?

Comment: Unless you are actually using `$scope` in controller, one of the main benefits of the `controllerAs` syntax is you can just do `new HelloController()` rather than having to go through the injector. This only works if you're using something like webpack, though, but IMO it's neater this way.

Comment: @DanPantry Thanks!  I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using controllerAs, `scope` will no longer be useful to you in tests like this one.  Instead, you need to look at the value returned from the call to `$controller`.  Your tests will pass as such:

```
  it('should call fetchArticle and set that to a property', function () {
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(ctl.greeting).to.equal('hello');
  });
```

As Dan Pantry says in the comments, you don't need `$controller` to instantiate HelloController.  Instead, you could do `new HelloController()`.